# how to pass parameters to partial view to show db content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting my content from a database. How can i use partial views to show content on page using that database?
database table: Content
[Id, Content] these are 2 fields

i want to get the content from db using partial views.
How i will pass an id to a partial view and show the content in view page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Html.RenderAction`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx):

```
public class MyController 
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Foo(int id) 
    {
        var content = GetContentFromDatabase(id);
        return Content(content, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    }
}
```

And in your view include the partial:

```
<%= Html.RenderAction("foo", "mycontroller", new { id = 5 }) %>
```

Remark: `RenderAction` is part of the now released ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM. For ASP.NET MVC 1 you may take a look at the [Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471) assembly containing this extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your view, use the `Html.RenderPartial` function.  There are a few different uses:

You can pass in a model to the partial view: `<% Html.RenderPartial("partialName", model); %>`

Or you can pass in a whole new `ViewDataDictionary`: `<% Html.RenderPartial("partialName", viewData); %>`

For the full documentation, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial.aspx).

**EDIT: (Answer to comment):**

I would include that data as part of you're view's model.  For example, let's say in your model you have:

```
 List<Person> People;
```

In your view, you want to loop through each one of these, and use a PartialView to display the details:

```
 <% foreach( var p in Model.People){ %>
         <p> <% Html.RenderPartial("personPartial", p); %> </p>
 <%}%>
```

Now, your PartialView might look like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Person>" %>
<%=Model.PersonName%>
```

Comment: What will i pass as model?
Lets say i want to show content for different paragraphs like this <p>[data here from db whose id=5]</p>, <p>[data here from db whose id=7]</p> and so on..

Comment: I dont want to show all p in Model.People, just want to show with some id like 5,8 etc.

Comment: Then only add that item to the Model.  I was using the list as an example.  The key is to add the object itself into the model, not just the ID of it.